# SMD 5050 LED 32.8' with 24v powersupply

Tags: led-strip

So im looking at buying this:
[http://www.amazon.com/SUPERNIGHT-Waterproof-Flexible-Changing-Controller/dp/B00MN6WTQC/ref=pd_cp_MI_1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MN6WTQC)

Wont the 24v 5a powersupply fry these?
The reviews are misleading. 
Is there a voltage regulator somewhere in the IR reciever im missing?
Thanks

Comment: Ten bucks says these are 6 led per segment 24v stripes, not 3 led 12v strips

Comment: And amazon reviews get lumped in alot

Answer (score 1):

Some strips come in 6 or 5 LEDs per segment like the one in the attached picture, and those LEDs are connected in series with a resistor (~330 Ohm), each color has its own power line and its own resistor per segment. So for such strip you need 24v, while more Amps will allow you to connect more segments/roles to the same controller.
[image]